# What is the fastest method to create and render large number of 2d sprites in Unity?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, optimization

I am creating an infinite terrain generator and I need to constantly update the terrain as the player moves around.

Everything is fine, but I am having trouble with finding information about the fastest method of creating and rendering sprites on the fly.

**Information about sprites:**

I am using 1 sprite sheet which has all the frames I need for my terrain. Grass, sand, water etc. all in 1 single .png file. All frames are stored in an array from which I can easily grab them.

**Steps I need to do to display my sprite object correctly currently:**

1. Create new object.
2. Set their position in 2d space.
3. Add component.
4. Scale them as needed.

Generated sprites get stored in a `GameObject` array called `chunk`. This is the way I am currently generating sprites.

```
        chunk[i] = new GameObject();
        chunk[i].gameObject.transform.position = new Vector2(spriteCoordX, spriteCoordY);
        chunk[i].AddComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        SpriteRenderer renderer = chunk[i].GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
        renderer.sprite = tiles[calculatedFrameId]; //Set correct sprite frame.
        chunk[i].gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector2(6.75f , 6.75f);
```

I don't know, adding component and scaling every single time I want to create a new sprite in code seems redundant and unnecessary and I am sure there is a better way to do that.

**To sum up:**

I need the best (fastest) possible way to generate large number of sprites, set their frame, position and proper scale.

Comment: use **texture atlas** for image sources. use **prefabs** for sprites.

Comment: the `new` operator in C# is slow. it would be faster if you would reuse old objects instead of destroying them. see http://gameprogrammingpatterns.com/object-pool.html

Comment: Have you checked out [Object pooling](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling)?

Comment: @FICHEKK care to show us how you are determining if `chunk[i]` needs to be set to a new GameObject?  Is this an initialize method or is it something that detects the players location and then creates a new GameObject if the player is entering a new area?

Comment: @FICHEKK, lastly do you need these objects to constantly be active or would a "custom" culling method suffice?(For tiles that are no longer visible)

Comment: @Eddge I didn't know about the better method than simply removing tiles that were out of camera view and generating ones that come in view when player enters a new area. Also, for now, tiles don't need to be active, what would be a good culling method for 2d game?

Comment: @FICHEKK I will write up a couple ways to do this, so you would have to choose one based on your needs, or modify them to suit your needs...  Might take some time...

Answer (score 1):

Cannot help posting this image here, as this is really of thousands of words, thanks @AidenH for the "Object pooling" comment!

[image]

Comment: This isn't really an answer! xD

Comment: Not necessarily to be in code. It is an answer, to me, :)

Answer (score 0):

I apologize this took me some time to get to...  I ended up creating a project where I generate an open world, and I use Perlin Noise to generate portions of the map depending on where the player is(Since I dont have an actual terrain)

I used Object Pooling for this, so I have a World Manager that knows what the world looks like (or in my case it uses Perlin Noise), this WorldManager pools tiles.

NOTE: This is one way to do it, using Object Pooling.

So basically it would look something like this:

```
public class WorldManager : MonoBehaviour {
    // Being cheap here for the time, if you use this route make sure to use a proper singleton pattern
    static public WorldManager instance; 

    [SerializeField]  // Created a prefab for all my tile objects
    private TileObject tilePrefab; 

    [SerializeField]
    private int StartingTilePool = 300;

    [SerializeField] // In my case this list stored 1 sprite, and I just changed that sprite color depending on the value of perlin noise
    List<Sprite> terrainSprites; 

    private Queue<TileObject> objectPool = new Queue<TileObject>();

    void Start() {
        instance = this; // Again use a proper singleton pattern in your project.
        GenerateTilePool();
        LoadFirstSetOfTiles();
    }

    private void LoadFirstSetOfTiles()
    {
        // my player always starts at 0,0..
        for(int x = -SpawnTileBoundry.HorizontalExtents; x <= SpawnTileBoundry.HorizontalExtents; ++x) 
        {
             for(int y = -SpawnTileBoundry.VerticalExtents; y <= SpawnTileBoundry.VerticalExtents; ++y) 
             {
                 SetActiveTile(x,y);
             }
        }
    }

    private void GenerateTilePool()
    {
        for(int i =0; i < tilesToGenerate; ++i)
        {
            TileObject tempTile = Instantiate(tilePrefab);
            EnqueTile(tempTile);
        }
    }

    public void EnqueTile(TileObject tile)
    {
        objectPool.Enqueue(tile);
        tile.gameObject.SetActive(false);
    }

    public void SetActiveTile(int x, int y)
    {
        TileObject newTile = null;
        if(objectPool.count > 0)
        {
            newTile = objectPool.Dequeue();
        }
        else
        {
            // We didn't have enough tiles store in our pool so lets make a new 1.
            newTile = Instantiate(tilePrefab);
        }         
        newTile.transform.position = new Vector3(x,y,1); // Used 1 to put it behind my player...
        newTile.gameObject.SetActive(true);
        // The sprite here would be based off of your world data, where mine is only a white box, I use the second parameters to give it a gray-scaled color.
        newTile.UpdateSprite(terrainSprites[0], Mathf.PerlinNoise(x/10.0f, y / 10.0f));
    }
}
```

That is just my WorldManager that handles ObjectPooling for me...
Here is my TileObject

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(SpriteRenderer))]
public class TileObject : MonoBehaviour {
    private SpriteRenderer myRenderer;
    private void Awake() {
        myRenderer = getComponent<SpriteRenderer>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if(Mathf.Abs(transform.position.x - Camera.main.transform.position.x) > SpawnTileBoundry.HorizontalExtents || Mathf.Abs(transform.position.y - Camera.main.transform.position.y) > SpawnTileBoundry.VerticalExtents) 
        {
            // With this check the tile knows it is no longer visible,
            // I could have used OnBecameInvisible to handle this
            // but I added a threshold to the extents, that prevent it so
            // players would see tiles "appearing" this caused a nice bug, where
            // if you moved just right a row/col of tiles wouldn't spawn.
            WorldManager.instance.EnqueTile(this);
        }
    }

    public void UpdateSprite(Sprite sprite)
    {
        myRenderer.sprite = sprite;
    }

    public void UpdateSprite(Sprite sprite, float grayColor)
    {
         UpdateSprite(sprite);
         myRenderer.color = new Color(grayColor,grayColor,grayColor,1f);
    }
}
```

Here is my SpawnTileBoundry script:

```
public class WorldManager : MonoBehaviour {
    private int lastX = 0;
    private int lastY = 0;
    static public int HorizontalExtents;
    static public int VerticalExtents;

    void Start() {
        VerticalExtents = (int)Camera.main.orthograpicSize + 2; // +2 is just my threshold
        HorizontalExtents = (int)(VerticalExtents * Screen.width/Screen.height) +3; // +3 is just my threshold you can change these to what you want.
        lastX = (int)transform.position.x;
        lastY = (int)transform.position.y;
    }

    void Update() {
        int newX = (int)transform.position.x;
        int newY = (int)transform.position.y;

        HandleNewTileSpawn(lastX - newX, lastY - newY);
    }

    // This will tell the WorldManager which tiles need to appear
    // We are no longer creating new tiles unless we absolutely have to.
    // We are also only making new tiles appear in the circumstance that
    // we are about to see them.
    void HandleNewTileSpawn(int x, int y)
    {
        if(x != 0) 
        {
            // This code could be refactor to a method so it was less error prone for  changes or tweaks...
            if(x < 0) 
            {
                for(int i = lastY - VerticalExtents; i < lastY + VerticalExtents; ++i)
                {
                    WorldManager.instance.SetActiveTile(lastX + HorizontalExtents, i);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                for(int i = lastY - VerticalExtents; i < lastY + VerticalExtents; ++i)
                {
                    WorldManager.instance.SetActiveTile(lastX - HorizontalExtents, i);
                }
            }
            lastX = (int)transform.position.x;
        }
        if(y != 0)
        {
            if(lastY < 0)
            {
                for(int i = lastX - HorizontalExtents; i < lastX + HorizontalExtents; ++i)
                {
                    WorldManager.instance.SetActiveTile(i, lastY + VeritcalExtents);
                }
            }
            else
            {
for(int i = lastX - HorizontalExtents; i < lastX + HorizontalExtents; ++i)
                {
                    WorldManager.instance.SetActiveTile(i, lastY - VeritcalExtents);
                }
            }
            lastY = (int)transform.position.y;
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the WorldManager to handle my object pooling, yes I am still instantiating quite a few sprites at the beginning but then I eventually stop spawning as there is no need to keep spawning new objects.

Unity doesn't have alot in their documentation in regards to object pooling however they do have a video tutorial that goes over some of the basics of Object Pooling: https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/topics/scripting/object-pooling