# Unity3D: How to modify Grid Layout Group component by script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

is there any way to change component setting of Constraint: "Fixed Row Count", by script, and then assigning constraint count to 1?

[image]

Comment: Did you look at the documentation: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.GridLayoutGroup.html  (Specifically the constraint and constraintCount Properties)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a script, .e.g. test.cs, add/attach this script to the same game object as the GridLayoutGroup:

[image]

```
public class test : MonoBehaviour {

    GridLayoutGroup glg;

    void Start () {        
        glg = gameObject.GetComponent<GridLayoutGroup>();
        Debug.Log(glg);
        glg.constraint = GridLayoutGroup.Constraint.FixedRowCount;  //**
        glg.constraintCount = 1;                                    //**
    }
}
```

Run the game, you will see this is automatically set to 1.

[image]

Comment: Just a suggestion maybe add a link to Unity's documentation as this entire question could have been avoided if they used it.

Comment: Thanks, but not necessarily have to do so. Different answer may have different styles. The snapshot is much easier to get the answer directly. Doc does not solve all problem. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: The documentation would have solved this issue, and yes answers have different styles, but educating someone how to find an answer instead of just giving them an answer would prevent a lot of duplicates.  I hope that makes sense.

Comment: No. I disagee. "the documentation would have solved this issue", if so, why so many questions here? You prefer doc, good, but no need to make it a must. Agree?

Comment: No I don't agree, specifically in the case to this question.  He asked how to update via script, checking the documentation, would have shown him how to update it via script.  I agree it doesn't solve all problems but something like this question, that is specifically about properties of a class rather then an algorithm of how to do something it would have solved.

Comment: I think some newbie is not willing to go through the docs, what they want is not a doc link, though it is easier for other developers. Look at the user, he is new here and may just want to get a quick go-through. Again, you prefer doc, no fault at all, but others prefer snapshots and code snippet, equally fine.

Comment: As a newbie that makes it even more important for him to learn about documentations and how to use them.

Comment: @Eddie, why bothering at this? The most important thing is to help others, right?

Comment: @Eddie, you are not wrong, but you should tolerate other styles of answer. Again, do not distract the OP, does it make sense? Already saw your comment, your style is no wrong, agreed on this already. But my preference is to make it easy, easier. Make sense?

Comment: Eddge, not Eddie.  I do tolerate other styles of answers as I was making a "suggestion" you are the one that stated it is better to just give them a direct answer which is what I disagree with.  Unless you plan on holding all new users hands through their whole projects?

Comment: A suggestion that would have taken you like a seconds to add, since I already posted the link in the comment of the question.

Comment: @Eddge, no comments. If you have this time, why don't you give solution to this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614740/what-is-the-fastest-method-to-create-and-render-large-number-of-2d-sprites-in-un, preferrably using the doc link. Thanks!

Comment: You obviously missed my point.  let me quote what I stated previously, "I agree it doesn't solve all problems but something like this question, that is specifically about properties of a class rather then an algorithm of how to do something it would have solved"

Comment: @Eddge, no comment again. Thank you.

Comment: I am taking a look at that question though.

Comment: @Eddge, great. Look forward to seeing your answers!