# Why using chuncks with infinite world creation (unity C# 2d top down)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, chunks, perlin-noise, topdown

I'm making a 2D top dowm survival game, I have Perlin-Noise working (I load different sprites based on the Perlin-Noise value) but now I'm at the point to spawn the "floor" inside camera-view and delete "floor" outside the camera-view. When I google or look at YouTube I only see tutorials where they use chunks.

My "floor" is made out of sprites and I use collisions (you can't walk on mountains for example)

Now I wonder if it has benefits to use chunks because in every chunk I have to make the sprites. I mean I have to make/load the sprites either way.

So I could:

1) I make chunks with for example 3x3 sprites and load them

2) I just load needed sprites (you could call it chunks of 1x1)

I can't find any benefit for 1) but all tutorials use chunks. So maybe I'm missing something

thank you for your time :)

Comment: I believe what you are talking about is called culling, only showing the items that are currently visible within the camera space.  I wrote an answer to a question about a faster way to load a bunch of 2d sprites.  It may be helpful to you... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614740/what-is-the-fastest-method-to-create-and-render-large-number-of-2d-sprites-in-un/51658132#51658132

Comment: Chunking, btw, is only there for faster rendering.  If you draw a lot of sprites in parallel as a big fat chunk, it's faster than one-by-one.  Read from https://forum.unity.com/threads/render-mode-chunk-vs-individual-any-more-info.444775/

Comment: Yes I meant culling :). So if I'm not getting issues because of slow rendering I don't need chunks? (my view is not that large I think, it's 85x48 sprites) On start I load the whole view and when the player for example walks to the right and exceeds a certain position I add a column of 48 sprites (I add them with a loop and the mathf.perlinnoise function) And then I delete 48 sprites on the left by using raycastAll because I know the position of the column to  delete. I do the same for other directions. I don't know if it's the best solution but it works :)

Answer (score 1):

I use a finite map, but the ideas are similar. I have a map where each cell has a size of 100*100 meters. For each of those cells I store high level stuff like the land form (e.g. hills, high mountains, ocean), biome (desert, snow, forest) & weather.

For each of those cells I can generate a map of many smaller cells using interpolation and extra noises. Those cells contain the information that changes from cell to cell in the same chunk.

Using large chunks can also help with render performance of terrain, because they can all share the same 3d mesh. The height is encoded in a texture and the shader accesses it.