# C# world tile map generator issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game that will contain a 1000 x 1000 tiled map in the shape of a square but I am having issues.

I tried making two different scripts to approach the issue. The first one was a sloppy approach to what I need. My second script is a more efficient approach to what I need.

Script 1:

```
 void fill()
    {
        for (float i = 0; i != 1000; i++)
        {
            Instantiate(GameObject.Find("Dirt"), new Vector2(xPos++, yPos), Quaternion.identity);
            xrepeat++;
            if (xrepeat == 1000)
            {
                xPos = 0;
                yPos = yPos - 1;
                yrepeat++;
                if(yrepeat != 1000)
                {
                    i = 0;
                    xPos = 0;
                }
                if(xPos < 0) //Prevents an overflow.
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Script 2:

```
    void buildx()
    {
        for (int i = 1000; i != 0; i--)
        {
            Instantiate(GameObject.Find("Dirt"), new Vector2(xPos++, yPos), Quaternion.identity);
            if (xPos == 1000)
            {
                buildy();
            }
        }
    }
    void buildy()
    {
        if (yPos == -1000)
        {
            Destroy(this); // Job is done, time to pack up
        }
        else
        {
            for (int i = 1000; i != 0; i--)
            {
                Instantiate(GameObject.Find("Dirt"), new Vector2(xPos, yPos--), Quaternion.identity);
                buildx();
            }
        }
    }
```

The first script duplicated my dirt block 1000 times then subtracts the y axis by 1 and repeat until it reaches the quota. That sort of worked but it gave up towards the end of the job. The Second script ping pongs back and forth between the x and y axis checking for the 1000 quota but it froze for some reason.

I pretty much abandoned script 1 in favor of script 2 because I thought script 2 was more efficient.

Is there any way how I can get script 2 to work?

Comment: _"My second script is a more efficient approach to what I need"_... how about you describe what you need then? You didn't tell us and you don't want us guessing. But taking my best guess: google [perlin noise tilemap](https://www.google.com/search?q=perlin+noise+tilemap). _"but it froze for some reason"_ That's what debuggers are for. Put some breakpoints in strategic places (or log/print some messages - 'aka poor man's debugging') and see what it does.

Comment: Well you can make it more efficient by removing your gameObject.Find("Dirt") every loop as that gets more expensive every time you instantiate a new gameObject, secondly instead of creating a "Tile" object for each object I would suggest looking into Object pooling.

Comment: I took a look at the first two comments. Very helpful advice by the way. I decided to clean up the second script some more by changing xPos to 0 in buildy() but it still seems to freeze. I looked into object pooling and toyed with the idea of making the players think that there are other tiles around them when in reality, the tiles are only created when the player breaks the tile adjacent to them.

Comment: To be honest I dont think either of those scripts are "more efficient" than the other... just use a double for loop.  if this is the route you are taking.

Comment: I also agree that neither of these scripts are "more efficient" than the other. Can you explain more on using a double for a loop? I'm still learning the basics.

Comment: I question what you are doing with the two methods `buildx` and `buildy`. As you commented, the `xPos` variable is simply increasing. Example in `buildx`… when `xPos` reaches 1000, `buildy` is called. Inside `buildy`, inside the for loop `for (int i = 1000; i != 0; i--)` … in “EACH” iteration it calls `buildx`, however, `xPos` is already 1000, therefore a new object is created for `xPos` 1001, 1002, 1003… up to 2000. It will NEVER enter `if(xPos == 1000)` and you do this 1000 times?  This can not be right.

Comment: Also, I changed my explanation since the first comment to this question. Forgive me for not saying this sooner.

Comment: @Matt I wrote an answer showing a basic double for loop for your use case.

Comment: Ah, thank you JohnG for pointing out a flaw in my code. `buildx` Shouldn't be decreasing. Silly me. I shall fix this.

Comment: I fixed the issue JohnG pointed out but it still froze because it was probably too costly to handle. I tried Eddge 's script but unity froze again. I will look more into object pooling and the idea I toyed with in an earlier comment I made.

Comment: @Matt well you are creating 1000000 objects it will take some time, try making a smaller size map first say 30x30 updated the script with 2 public variables you can change in the inspector to test different sizes.

Comment: @Eddge So maybe I should try to make the 1000x1000 map 30x30 at a time? Sounds like a better idea than what I tried.

Comment: @Matt I would get a small size map working first so you know your algorithm works, then do incremental tests to see when you need to worry about optimizing your tilemap

Comment: @Eddge Alright, I shall do that. I managed to get the first test working. I shall mark your answer as the answer. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would highly recommend looking into Unity's job system, but your loops are incredibly confusing, not sure what is going there... It also seems you are way over complicating this.  So this is how I would approach instantiate a map of 1000x1000 tiles if I had to instantiate them all:

```
public int mapWidth = 30;
public int mapHeight = 30;

void fill()
{
    // Doing this once at the beginning, so it isn't super expensive...
    GameObject basePrefab = GameObject.Find("Dirt"); 
    // Creating 1 Vector3 that we can just update the values on
    Vector3 spawnPosition = Vector3.zero;

    for(int x = 0; x < mapWidth; ++x)
    {
        // Update the spawn x Position
        spawnPosition.x = x;
        for(int y = mapHeight; y > 0; y--)
        {
            // Update the spawn y position
            spawnPosition.y = y;
            Instantiate(basePrefab, spawnPosition, Quaternion.identity);
        }
    } 
}
```

If you want to read about or see an example for object pooling for a tile map like system, here is an answer I wrote awhile ago that should give you the geist of it: [What is the fastest method to create and render large number of 2d sprites in Unity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51614740/what-is-the-fastest-method-to-create-and-render-large-number-of-2d-sprites-in-un/51658132#51658132)